# Searching within column with mysql LIKE miltiple times

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I need to search a column for a string ,multiple times for variation of the same string, so i did this

```
SELECT * 
FROM `users` 
WHERE user = 'king'
OR alias = 'king'
OR aliases LIKE '%,king%'
OR aliases LIKE '%king,%'
OR aliases LIKE '%king,%'
```

the column `aliases` will contains words separated with comma e.g `king,queen,knight` etc
But because like itself is slow, i am wondering if there is any way i can optimize this query

Comment: In case you are wondering why this query is slow, that's the design decision to put multiple things in a single column came back to bite you. Unfortunately, denormalization is like that.

Comment: Create a relational table of aliases

Comment: if i have to put the aliases in another table, then i'll have to perform two query or more

Comment: @Smith Not really - you can query multiple tables in a single `select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `users` 
WHERE user = 'king'
OR alias = 'king'
OR FIND_IN_SET ('king', aliases)>0;
```

Comment: is this faster than `like`